# Azure AppInsight Log Information not working

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

In Asp.net Core version 3.1 I have tried to log LogInformation to Application Insights, but it is not logging in App Insight.

```
private readonly ILogger<LogService> _logger;

public LogService(IOptions<LogConfig> logConfig, ILogger<LogService> logger)
 {
    _logConfig = logConfig.Value;

    _logger = logger;
 }
_logger.LogInformation("Parameters: {Log Info}", _logConfig.IsLogEnabled);
```

But Logging Error is working

```
_logger.LogError(e, "Parameters: {HttpMethod}, {ErrorCode}", logEntry.HttpMethod, logEntry.ErrorCode);
```

Using package ***Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore*** version ***2.21.0***

In Startup.cs

```
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
```

In appSettings.Development.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    }
  },
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    },
    "ConnectionString": "secret"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you create a resource for the app insights? (in Azure)

Comment: @mattsharp Yes, Logs are visible in App Insight also Errors but can't log Log Information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the AI loglevel at the incorrect level. It should be like this:

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    },
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information"
      }
    }
  },
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "ConnectionString": "secret"
  }
}
```

Comment: This is working !! Thanks. I have one more doubt about how to avoid logging trace.